# how to generate access token for azure service principal

Tags: rest, bearer-token, azure-service-principal

i need to generate token for Azure Service principal and want to use in my automation rest api bdd project how to obtain it ?using java, currently i am using Azure cli to generate token,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Retrieve access token from SPN using Python**

install msal package of Python---[msal library](https://pypi.org/project/msal/)

```
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
scope= 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
tenant_id = "XXXX-XXX-XXXX"
client_id = "XXXX-XXX-XXXX"
client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
authority_uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}".format(tenant_id)
app=ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client_id,authority=authority_uri,client_credential= client_secret)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
print(result['access_token'])
```